# How to change column width for particular row of table

Tags: tables, tabularx, width, renewcommand, linewidth

How can I set this layout?
[image]

I have made this but it did not work

```
\begin{table}[H] 
\caption{Current state-of-the-art approaches in UAV fault detection techniques.\label{tab:2}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCCl}
\toprule
\textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Signal Processing}   & \textbf{Machine Learning in Artificial Intelligence} &  \textbf{Main Remarks}\\
\midrule
data    & Yes           & No &  Fault diagnosis/control using motor speeds\\
data        & Yes           & No  &  Fault diagnosis/control using motor speeds\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Because I got this result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with it does not work? Please explain better. Do you have an error message? If yes add it to your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to my why you don't want to abbreviate "Machine Learning in Artificial Intelligence" as "ML in AI" in one of the header cells.

Anyway, the following may be close to what you're looking for. Note that I see no need to **bold-face** the contents of the header cells. Do trust your readers to be able to figure out where the header row is even if its contents **aren't typeset in bold**.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other appropriate document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{This is a table caption.\label{tab1}}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lccL @{}}
\toprule
Ref. & 
\makecell[t]{Signal\\Processing} & 
\makecell[t]{Machine Learning in\\Artificial Intelligence} & 
Main Remarks\\
\midrule
{[1]} & Data & Data & Fault diagnosis\slash control using motor speeds\\ 
{[2]} & Data & Data & Fault diagnosis\slash control using motor speeds\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I only added this to the head of the table "\textbf{\makecell[t]{Signal \\ Processing}}" and, fortunately, it worked, however, thank you very much for your help.